# arm_navigation visualization error: No default planner configuration defined under 'default_planner_config'

Tags: arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Wizards,

I am trying out the new (and incredibly awesome) arm [navigation planning wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Automatically%20Generating%20Arm%20Navigation%20Configurations/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard) on my home built robot ([Pi Robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pi_description)).  The wizard runs flawlessly and I generated a planning group called "left arm" that runs from the torso link to the left hand link.

Next I wanted to try the planning components visualizer so I launched the automatically created planning_components_visualizer.launch file.  Most of the nodes fired up fine until I ran into the following error:

```
No default planner configuration defined under 'default_planner_config'. A default planner must be defined from among the configured planners
```

The full output from the launch file looks like this:

```
core service [/rosout] found
process[wall_clock_server-1]: started with pid [2005]
process[environment_server-2]: started with pid [2006]
process[planning_scene_validity_server-3]: started with pid [2007]
process[pi_robot_left_arm_kinematics-4]: started with pid [2008]
process[ompl_planning-5]: started with pid [2009]
process[trajectory_filter_server-6]: started with pid [2010]
process[rviz_planning_components-7]: started with pid [2011]
process[planning_components_visualizer-8]: started with pid [2012]
process[rob_st_pub-9]: started with pid [2013]
[ INFO] [1310134526.200470474, 1310134526.196687936]: Environment server started
[ INFO] [1310134526.269147358, 1310134526.258922100]: waitForService: Service [/ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1310134526.544622151, 1310134526.542999029]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /planning_scene_validity_server
[ INFO] [1310134526.544764147, 1310134526.542999029]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /ompl_planning
[ INFO] [1310134526.746567756, 1310134526.741112947]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /pi_robot_left_arm_kinematics
[ INFO] [1310134526.848666707, 1310134526.845432043]: Successfully connected to planning scene action server for /trajectory_filter_server
[ INFO] [1310134527.267298212, 1310134527.264225959]: Waiting for planner service /ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path
[ INFO] [1310134527.268940800, 1310134527.264225959]: waitForService: Service [/ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ERROR] [1310134527.285647063, 1310134527.274550914]: No default planner configuration defined under 'default_planner_config'. A default planner must be defined from among the configured planners
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10527/arm_navigation-visualization-error:-no-default-planner-configuration-defined-under-%27default_planner_config%27.-a-default-planner-must-be-defined-from-among-the-configured-planners/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add the following line at the end of your auto-generated YAML configuration file for OMPL (config/ompl_planning.yaml):

default_planner_config: SBLkConfig1

We'll update the gui soon so it reflects this change and adds the line in automatically.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-07-11**:
Fixed on trunk, will be released shortly.  Sorry for the omission!

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-07-08**:
Thanks Sachin--works like a charm now!